# Why the amount of used memory increases even after the memory is released?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, new-operator

I found that  the amount of used memory increases even after the memory is released in my program. So I wrote two simple C++ test programs to verify it.

```
#define NUM 1000000
void Test1()
{
    PrintMemory("Test1 Beginning");
    double* Data = new double[NUM];

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        Data[i] = std::rand() % 1000;
    }

    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        sum += Data[i];
    }

    delete [] Data;
    PrintMemory("end");
}

double* Data[NUM];
void Test2()
{
    PrintMemory("Test2 Beginning");

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        Data[i] = new double;
        *(Data[i]) = std::rand() % 1000;
    }

    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        sum += *(Data[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        delete Data[i];
    }
    PrintMemory("end");
}

void main()
{
    Test1();
    Test2();
}
```

In the function `PrintMemory` I call the API `GetProcessMemoryInfo` to obtain the information about used memory that is the field `PrivateUsage` of the structure `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX`.

The output is as follows:

> MemUsed: 5544kb in Test1 Beginning
>   MemUsed: 5568kb in end
>   MemUsed: 5568kb in Test2 Beginning
>   MemUsed: 6404kb in end

I can't figure out the output. I expect that after the `delete` is called the amount of used memory should recover to the former value.  The amount of used memory is related to the 
call number of the operators `new` and `delete`.

Comment: For better help, format your code in a readable way.

Comment: @m0skit0 Have you read *the whole* question or only the code?

Answer (score 3):

With one million of `DOUBLE` values, the amount of memory you need for the payload alone is 8 MB. Your prints show that private usage does not increase by that much, and that is the memory is actually released correctly.

What you are not taking into consideration however, is that `new` does not allocate from bare memory, it takes blocks from heap and when they are returned back they might still - to some extent - attribute to process waiting for new allocations "cached".

This is what you see: with one big allocation/deallocation memory usage increased just a bit. With a million of small allocations it increased more, but still way less than actual payload size. If you repeat allocations, you will see that at some point the memory will not go up further and all the remains that you see are just fragmentation and heap allocation artifacts.

Comment: Thanks, Roman. Is there any document that describes what Windows does when the operators new and delete are called? For the extra memory, is it possible to clean the extra memory up?

Comment: It is now Windows doing this for you. `new` and `delete` are implemented by C++ runtime, which internally uses Windows API. Cleaning (in terms of excluding it from performance metrics) all unused memory is just impossible because of allocation fragmentation. If you want to be "byte accurate" you will need to implement your own memory manager from the ground, and override `new`/`delete` operators to switch to your own implementation.

Comment: A fixed size of memory is allocated each time. Does memory fragmentation occur to this simple test program?

Comment: You cannot be sure because you are not aware of internals of heap manager operation. Does it have separate pool for tiny allocations, does it merge free blocks when they are released or leaves as it for future reuse etc. Compared to what you allocate, the machine has a plenty of RAM and it does not have or need to immediately free every single byte of no longer used memory.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the extra memory is actually not directly to do with the amount of heap used here. It may be some extra memory management overhead and similar, rather than actual memory allocations. As Roman points out, you're allocating 8MB, and that's much more than the rather small differences in your printout. Instead what happens is that when you allocate a lot of small blocks, more overhead is used to track the memory allocations, and that is what takes up more memory in the second case. Of course, that memory isn't directly part of your allocations, so when the actual memory is released, it's not actually freed as such.

I'd put that down to "Just the way it is"...

I expect if you run test1 and test2 50 times each, the memory usage won't continue to go up at some point - it may not happen immediately, but after a few runs, it will reach "steady state".